# Behaviour of combo-boxes items, will they perform their actions if a previous variable defines what combo-box i'm in?

Tags: c#, combobox

It's the following, i have 1 combo-box with item1 and item2

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

        if (ComboBox1.SelectedItem == "item1")
        {
            variableA = 0;
        }
        else if (ComboBox1.SelectedItem == "item2")
        {
             variableA = 1;
        }
    }
```

and early in the program i have another variable that sets what item the combobox is in, for example

```
int variablecomboboxitem = 1;

if (variablecomboboxitem == 1) {ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "item1"} 
else if (variablecomboboxitem == 2 ){ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "item2"}
```

but, for diverse reasons i might need to start with variablecomboboxitem = 2;

the question is.. when i set the variablecomboboxitem = 1 early on the program, the item1 will show up in the combobox, but will it load variableA = 0??? or will he just set the item on the combobox???

if he doesn't load the variableA value, how can i make it so that he performs the actions after the combo-box item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question properly, you're essentially asking if the `SelectedIndexChanged` event will be raised if you set the selected index programmatically.

The answer is yes. Setting the selected index of a combo box programmatically (e.g. by modifying the `SelectedIndex` property in the constructor) *will* raise the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, and therefore cause the code in your event handlers to be executed. If you set the selected index to 1, `variableA` will be set to 0. If you set the selected index to 2, `variableA` will be set to 1. Or whatever logic your code in the event handler method implements.

Of course, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is only raised when the selected index is *changed*. If you set the selected item to "item1" in the constructor, and then the user *re-selects* "item1", the event won't be fired again. But that's probably what you want. The value of `variableA` wouldn't change anyway by your current logic.

Comment: thank you, will the same happen if, for example, instead of a combobox, it's a checkbox? The checkbox1_checkedchanged is an event, if checkbox1.checked = true, does "something". But i set, trough a variable on the program start that if variablecheckbox =1, then checkbox1.checked = true. Will it perform "something"? Is it possible to change only the checkbox state, but not performing the following actions? @Cody Gray

Comment: @César Yes, the events will fire regardless of how the state is changed. That's true for combo boxes and check boxes. If you *don't* want it to happen, you have some work ahead of you. You'll either have to set a flag variable while you do the update and check the value of that flag inside of the event handler method, or you'll have to unsubscribe from the `XxxChanged` event, change the state, and re-subscribe. More info on that is in [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477369/issue-in-checkedchanged-event).

Comment: very helpful @Cody, i have nearly 1500 lines of code, and didn't thought about the possibility of that issue, been holding my breath for the last minutes :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the framework's design is correct. Regardless of how the value is changed, the changed event should fire. You really should re-think your design if you need something different. But you're welcome. :-)

Comment: I came up with an additional question for this, if i set the variablecomboboxitem = 1; on the initialize, how will it assume the combobox item has changed? Because considering that, it probably would assume no value to variableA.

Comment: @César I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Initially, a combobox has *nothing* selected. If, during initialization, you set the selected item (whether to item 0, item 1, or whatever), then the changed event will fire.

Comment: you answered it :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

yes, `variableA=0` will be the value.

I am not illustrating this anymore. Cody Gray's explanation is great!